# Añadir variables a un XML usando C#

Tags: c#, xml

Necesito saber una forma más "practica" donde pueda agregar informacion variable a estos puntos de un XML. Actualmente lo hago así:

```
        'sendXML += "<category>" + tagCategory/*categoria*/ + "</category>";
        sendXML += "<subcategory>" + tagSubcategory/*subcategoria*/ + "</subcategory>";
        sendXML += "<item>" + tagItem/*elemento*/ + "</item>";'
```

Se los agradecería. Gracias

Comment: No se si te refieres a esto, pero podrías usar [String.Format](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Si ese dato está en el web.config de tu proyecto puedes acceder a ellos mediante la librería **ConfigurationManager**, el cuál te da la posibilidad de acceder, setear y leer dichos parámetros.

Ejemplo:

```
var cadena = String.Empty;
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["category"] = cadena;
```